# Adding Div dynamically to my web page as per the contents in the table using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display every individual record from table on my web page, if the records in table increases the number of div should also increase.
How do i achieve this using ASP.net.
Please if any one can guide me as i am new to ASP.Net
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated earlier using MVC would be a nice approach but u will have to learn a bit to use it.
As per the current scenario you can use repeaters which are exactly designed for what you want to accomplish.

assuming your database looks something similar to this..

```
id int  primary key 
name  nvarchar(50)
```

etc...
//suppose you have your database data in `"dataFromDatabase"`
now in your asp.net page just define a repeater like this

```
<div id="content">
   <asp:repeater id="repeaterData" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
     <Table>
        <tr>
           <th>Id:</th>
           <th>Name : </th>
        </tr>
   </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <td><%#Eval("id")%></td>
       <td><%#Eval("name")%></td>
     </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
     </Table>
   </FooterTemplate>
</repeater>
</div>
```

and in your .aspx.cs page

bind the repeater with your datasource

```
repeaterData.DataSource = dataFromDatabase
repeaterData.DataBind();
```

thats all you need to do to get it up and  running...

and using `GridView` would be even more simpler  you just need to drag that from `ToolBox` to your aspx file and select your data Source visually and violla  you are done... no coding required.....
although you will have to do some coding for the edit, delete and some fancy stuff...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking to implement a [repeater class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater).

**EDIT**
Here is some sample code per your request from the link mentioned above:

```
<asp:Repeater
    DataMember="string"
    DataSource="string"
    DataSourceID="string"
    EnableTheming="True|False"
    EnableViewState="True|False"
    ID="string"
    OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
    OnDisposed="Disposed event handler"
    OnInit="Init event handler"
    OnItemCommand="ItemCommand event handler"
    OnItemCreated="ItemCreated event handler"
    OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound event handler"
    OnLoad="Load event handler"
    OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"
    OnUnload="Unload event handler"
    runat="server"
    Visible="True|False"
>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </FooterTemplate>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Sort of, but am not aware of repeater class implementation. Is there any other way?

Comment: @user2094793: The `Repeater` control is made for exactly what you're describing.  Why do you need another way?  I suppose you could just manually output the table contents in a loop, but why re-invent the wheel?  This control does what you need.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the suggestions, it would be great if i get any sample code of it.

Comment: @user2094793: The MSDN documentation provides some: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx

Comment: @TouchingTheVoid: It sounds like your trying to get someone to write your code for you without attempting to solve the problem yourself. You'll have better luck by attempting to write something and submitting it to the community for review. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gridview` or `repeater` to solve your.

Gridview basic example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0

Repeater basic example
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're completely new to ASP.NET, I'd suggest working with the ASP.NET MVC Framework instead of with WebForms. Ultimately it's a matter of taste, but the MVC framework has been designed with the deliberate goal of making it easy to write good quality code, so if you're starting fresh anyway you might as well learn to do it well from the beginning.

The best place to start is probably at the [official site of ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). They have a good "getting started"-guide, and [lots and lots of tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4) on levels from absolute beginner to advanced web developing.

*And a side note to all the WebForms fans out there: I'm definitely not saying you can't write good quality code with WebForms - however, if you look around the internet most examples you find are poorly constructed and full of antipatterns. Starting with ASP.NET MVC Framework yields a higher chance of the web resources you find demonstrating good practices, rather than quick hacks.*

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
 for(int i= 0;i<10i++){
            label.text="<div>"+something+"</div>"+label.text
        }
```